# Handle XML output in Vagrant

Tags: xml, powershell, vagrant

I have PowerShell script which parse XML with auto test results

```
PS C:\vagrant\S_T> [xml]$testresult = Get-Content 'C:\vagrant\S_T\TestResult.xml'
PS C:\vagrant\S_T> $testresult.selectNodes('//test-run') | select failed
```

Which gives me correct output

```
failed
------
5
```

Now I need to know if it is possible to handle number from XML in Vagrant and send output to local machine (not Vagrant machine) via PowerShell.

For example:

If failed value > 0 than print text "Auto tests are failed" (in PowerShell console on local machine).

If failed value < 0 than print text "Auto test are passed" (in PowerShell console on local machine).

Comment: seems that the specflow tag is unnecessary here

Comment: I have no idea what Vagrant is, but based on some keywords you've used, I'm wondering if this could be a situation where you need to do some PS remoting. IOW launch a script on your local workstation that will execute things remotely on the Vagrant machine you mentioned in a comment below, and then display the results locally.

Comment: @ Poorkenny interesting idea, thanks. But Vagrant has its own provision that provides ability to execute PowerShell scripts and cmdlets inside Vagrant machine (for example Win 10). Maybe I can create separate script and connect to Vagrant machine via PS remoting and run my script not by Vagrant provision but via PS remoting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$testresult = [xml]'<a><test-run><failed>5</failed></test-run></a>'
[int]$failed = $testresult.selectNodes('//test-run/failed').InnerText

if ($failed -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Tests failed"
} else {
    Write-Host "Test succeded"
}
```

Comment: first of all - thank you - this script works on Vagrant machine, but I need to see output of this command not in Vagrant machine but on my local machine - so if I run this script as part of my auto tests I will see "Tests failed" or "Tests succeed" directly in PowerShell on local PC.